# What are the difference between business logic and UI logic?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc, flutter-state

I am learning state management in `flutter` and most of the time I encounter with words `business logic` `ui logic` and some time `presentation logic`, I searched it on the internet as people explain it in different languages, I couldn't get a better understanding, Could someone please show these three types of `logic` in the form of an example and explain it very clean and easy?

Answer (score 6):

When we use a library, it is our responsibility and mission to separate it from critical parts of our code, which is the Business Logic.
In Clean Architecture, for example, which respects those principles, the goal is to separate the concerns and roles that can be categorized into: 
1) UI (User Interface)
2) Formatter (the format, the legal part, the content)
3) Business Logic (the Business rules)
4) Data (can be in-memory, networks like APIs or Online Database or local persistent store/database)

Using cross-platform/multi-platform solutions like a flutter on the UI part can be a bit more logical than on the Business part. 
**The Business Logic** doesn't change frequently, but there might be frequent change wile developing UI.
For example, for networking calls, we can either implement this layer by ourselves or depend on a well-known library. If tomorrow a new better one shows up, we only need to replace the implementation of our layer without impacting the whole module or project.
Sometimes when a client says that app needs new UI with the same features, The might have been built at the way there must only be a change in UI mostly, without affecting the logic of features behind.
In the context of flutter, consider the example of a basic app of increment of press count, The logic should be separated (maybe in other class/file) so if we need to change pressing 1,2,3 times press to a,b,c... times press, the only business logic should be changed.
Follow The example below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 65;
  String hello = "a";

  // the only business logic change will be here...No UI change require
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      hello = String.fromCharCode(_counter);
      if(_counter!=90)
        _counter++;
      else
        _counter = 65;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$hello',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Still not getting the idea, refer below:
[(1)](https://medium.com/@abderrahim.benmakhlouf/why-flutter-react-native-should-not-be-part-of-your-business-logic-the-duty-of-the-developer-f7195b07d90d), [(2)](https://www.netguru.com/codestories/flutter-bloc), [(3)](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4074597-getting-started-with-the-bloc-pattern)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, bcz of ur efforts I am voting up ur answer.

Could you please show me the `UI logic` in your example? and also `presentation logic`? and here the business logic is the `counter variable` or the `incrementing` or `setState` ?

Comment: UI logic is how the content is been showing on the screen,(build method), business logic is you provide input to the code returning the output you require. (Methods/classes etc.). Setstate apparently updates the value in UI. Business logic is independent of the platform. like if you want to make your app in a prior base of the web, the UI will be changed like appear converts in a drawer, but the logic you implemented will remain same thoroughly.